# Prove that for all $x \in R$ at least one of $\sqrt{3}-x$ or $\sqrt{3}+x$ is irrational

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Prove that for all $x \in R$ at least one of $\sqrt{3}-x$ or $\sqrt{3}+x$ is irrational.

Could you not just prove this using contradiction by plugging in $1$ for 
$x$?

I'm having difficulty even starting this proof.

Comment: You are asked to prove it for all $x$, so plugging in one value will not work.  If you wanted to disprove the claim you could find one value where it failed, but here the claim is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If for *any* $x \in \Bbb R$,

$\sqrt 3 + x, \; \sqrt 3 - x \in \Bbb Q, \tag 1$

then

$2\sqrt 3 = (\sqrt 3 + x) + (\sqrt 3 - x) \in \Bbb Q, \tag 2$

whence

$\sqrt 3 \in \Bbb Q, \tag 3$

contradicting the irrationality of $\sqrt 3$; thus, (1) is false.

Comment: So the clue to an approach is "at least one is". Assume "both aren't", and get the contradiction.  :-)

Comment: @timtfj:  yes.  Simple logic.   $\not \exists x p(x) \equiv \forall x \neg p(x)$.

Comment: I'm afraid I think of it as $A+B=\overline {\overline A \cdot \overline B}$ for this one, but that's my background showing itself ;-) (And having just typed that, I can see why nobody here is using overbars in boolean expressions! It was a nightmare.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any other approaches to this proof?

Comment: @John:  probably, but I'd have to think about it to find an example.  Thanks for the "acceptance"!  Cheers!